# Babelify install complains about absence package.json

Tags: ecmascript-6, browserify, babeljs

When I try to install [Babelify](https://github.com/babel/babelify) locally:

```
npm install --save-dev babelify
```

I get the following error:

```
saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/project/package.json'
```

What does this mean? Should I add/open package.json manually? What should it contain?

Comment: BTW Trying to run 'npm install' results in the same error.

Comment: do you have a `package.json` in your project? it should be on the same folder level than `node_modules`.

Comment: No I do not.... is it necessary for a local project that I won't share with other devs? Babelify does run without it.

Comment: i think the `--save-dev` option tries to write the dependency into `package.json` and throws the error, because he can not find the file.